# To read each file and execute the func in loop

Tags: c, shell

I have 5000 files in my hard-disk with name as ip_file_1,ip_file_2,....
I have a executable that can merge only 2 files. How can I write a script that takes all the file residing in the hardisk (whichs start with ip_file_*) and calls the function for merging all the files.

I have a 5000 files which are binaries that contain the logging information (time that each function call has taken). I have another executable that takes only two files and merges according to the timestamp and gives the merged output.

I execute with the format like the below,

```
./trace ip_file1 ip_file2 mergefile  # I'm not using the trace tool. It's an example
```

I could use the executable to merge only two files. I thought of automating it to merge all the other files.

The merges has to be done in order (merged according to the timestamp). The logic to merge is already there. And the Output of the merge is sent to the file.

My question is not on how to merge the files. My question is how to automate and merge all the files instead of two files.

Comment: What do you mean by "takes the I/P from the stdin"? Could you spell out what you are trying to do?

Comment: I see several questions here. one is getting data from stdin(wtf, RTFM, google) another one to call a function (again, wtf), and an implied third, to do a sequence of merges (again, trivial). come up with *one specific question*.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think you should put your comment down as the answer :-)

Comment: Hmn, one important factor here, does the order of merging matter, such as is merge(merge(1, 2), 3) the same as merge(merge(1,3),2) to give some vague pseudo code to demonstrate? Also please clarify, do you want a C program which uses an existing lib, or a bash script run a full c program in sequence?

Comment: @Angus So you want to take all 5000 files and merge them into a single file?

Comment: `cat ip_file_* >merged_file` ?

Comment: You'll need to explain your merge tool a little more. If I did `merge A B` then took the result (`C`) and had another IP file called `D` could I then do `merge C D`? Does `merge` send output to another specified file, or to stdout?

Comment: @mbratch : I have edited my question according to your queries.

Comment: *The merges has to be done in order*. What kind of order?

Comment: @mbratch: I have edited my question again.

Comment: Are the filenames numerically sorted in the same order as the timestamps?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes Charles . Its numerically sorted according to the timestamp

Comment: @Angus, ...and are they zero-padded, such that a lexical sort and a numerical sort will be identical?

Comment: Is timestamp in the name or are you relying on the last-modified date in the file system?

Comment: Its not last modified time. The file contains a field that say how much time a function has taken to execute

Answer (score 1):

To avoid excessive number of parameters or length of parameters to a command line, you want to write your `merge` command so that it can take a previously merged output and merge another file. The description of `merge` in the original problem statement is quite scant, so I'll make the assumption that you can do this:

```
 merge -o output_file input_file
```

Where `output_file` can be a previously merged file or a new file. If you can do that, then it would be simple to merge all of them by:

```
find drive_path -name "ip_file_*" -exec merge -o output_file {} \;
```

The order here is directory order in the file system. If a different order is needed, that will need to be specified.

**ADDENDUM**

If you need the files in timestamp order, then I would revamp this approach and create a `merge` command that accepts as an input a text file which lists all of the files to merge. Create this list of files using the information given in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified

Comment: Re: addendum -- I have a short snippet of shell at the bottom of my answer which generates an array of filenames sorted by mtime (on bash, with tools having GNU extensions available).

Answer (score 1):

Where your external merge tool is `real_merge`, and this tool writes merged output from two command-line arguments to stdout, the following recursive shell function will do the job:

```
merge_files() {
  next=$1; shift
  case $# in
    0) cat "$next" ;;
    1) real_merge "$next" "$1"
    *) real_merge "$next" <(merge_files "$@")
  esac
}
```

This approach is highly parallelized -- which means that it'll use as much CPU and disk IO as is available to it. Depending on your available resources, and your operating system's facility at managing those resources, this may or may not be a good thing.

The other approach is to use a temporary file:

```
swap() {
  local var_curr=$1
  local var_next=$2
  local tmp

  tmp="${!var_curr}"
  printf -v "$var_curr" "${!var_next}"
  printf -v "$var_next" "$tmp"
}

merge_files() {
  local tempfile_curr=tempfile_A
  local tempfile_next=tempfile_B
  local tempfile_A="$(mktemp -t sort-wip-A.XXXXXX)"
  local tempfile_B="$(mktemp -t sort-wip-B.XXXXXX)"
  while (( $# )); do
    if [[ -s ${!tempfile_curr} ]]; then
      # we already populated our temporary file
      real_merge "${!tempfile_curr}" "$1" "${!tempfile_next}"
      swap tempfile_curr tempfile_next
    elif (( $# >= 2 )); then
      # only two arguments at all
      real_merge "$1" "$2" "${!tempfile_curr}"
      shift
    else
      # only one argument at all
      cat "$1"
      rm -f "$tempfile_A" "$tempfile_B"
      return
    fi
    shift
  done
  # write output to stdout
  cat "${!tempfile_curr}"
  # ...and clean up.
  rm -f "$tempfile_A" "$tempfile_B"
}
```

You can invoke it as: `merge_files ip_file_*` if the filenames' lexical sort order is accurate. (This will be true if their names are zero-padded, ie. `ip_file_00001`, but not true if they aren't padded). If not, you'll need to sort the stream of names first. If you're using bash and have GNU stat and sort available, this could be done as so:

```
declare -a filenames=()
while IFS='' read -r -d ' ' timestamp && IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
  filenames+=( "$filename" )
done < <(stat --printf '%Y %n\0' ip_file_* | sort -n -z)
merge_files "${filenames[@]}"
```

Comment: The records produced from the trace are one after the other padded with ip_file_01,ip_file_02,.... The merge tool I have will merge 1 & 2 (only two i/p files it takes not all the 5000 files)according to the timestamp, I need to manually take the o/p from the 1st two and call the merge tool to merge the o/p with 3,...etc